# Проигрывание .wav файлов

Tags: android

Ранее я искал способ записи нескольких звуков в высоком качестве. Нашел данный способ: [Android WAV audio recording](http://i-liger.com/article/android-wav-audio-recording). Там предполагается использование wav для записи в высоком качестве. Проблема в том, что стандартный MediaPlayer не поддерживает проигрывание wav файлов. Так вот, как можно реализовать проигрывание wav файлов?

Comment: Если честно, я не очень понял, как, используя метод, приведенный в статье, записывать одновременно несколько звуков: там вроде просто используют AudioRecord вместо MediaRecorder для записи звука.

Comment: Сейчас проблема в воспроизведении wav-файлов. Какими способами можно реализовать их воспроизведение?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Стандартный MediaPlayer [поддерживает](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html) воспроизведение wave-файлов при условии, что это 16 бит PCM.

> PCM/WAVE 8- and 16-bit linear PCM (rates up to limit of hardware) WAVE (.wav)

Если будет решено использовать AudioRecord, нужно выбрать формат

```
android.media.AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT
```

и он должен проигрываться в MediaPlayer.

P.S. Вам может пригодиться пример кода по работе со звуком: [ringdroid](http://code.google.com/p/ringdroid/).

Comment: Спасибо, попробую. Хотелось бы уточнить, ранее я делал приложение, которое тоже было связано со звуком, так вот там звук был в .wma (не моя прихоть), и после релиза у 25% была проблема, что звук не воспроизводился. Как только мы переформатнули в мп3, все стало на свои места. Допустим, на моем Desire HD .wma воспроизводился. Так в чем было дело? И не будет ли такого сейчас?

Comment: Трудно сказать. И wma, и mp3 - это форматы, их воспроизведение зависит от наличия в системе кодеков, а wav - это контейнер, он может содержать внутри разные форматы, в том числе те же wma и mp3. Поскольку PCM - это самый базовый формат, он должен воспроизводиться везде, где только можно. Правда размеры файлов могут быть великоваты.

Comment: У нас 90+ файлов, в общей сложности под сжатием, получилось 3.6 метра. (звуки по несколько секунд)

Comment: Кстати, мой Desire HD воспроизводит все форматы, все по дефолту, я ничего не обновлял.